# Tomcat server inside eclipse 4.3 issues with paths

Tags: tomcat, zk, server.xml

I am running a tomcat server inside eclipse 4.3 but am having issues with paths on my server. e. g.  this link returns a 404, but I'm sure the file is in the correct place (the root of web app)

```
http://localhost:8081/fooAppName/style.css
```

in eclipses tomcat `server.xml`

```
   <Context docBase="Monitor" path="/fooAppName" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:Monitor"/></Host>
```

My `index.zul` file gets run fine though (this is the one that is trying to load the `style.css`)

**Edit:**

But the paths work fine in a standalone tomcat deployment.

Comment: Is this CSS provided by you and its a ZK CSS?

Comment: yeah I provide it, buts also other files like img's. the only file I can go to is index.zul in the eclipse tomcat run, see my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of way to declare the CSS in ZK One way is add to `zk.xml`

```
       <desktop-config>
               <theme-uri>/resource/style/my.css</theme-uri>
       </desktop-config>
```

And Another way is add in your zul something like this

```
<style src="/resource/style/login.css" />
```

Comment: Is this css outside project diretory?